# Leaflet on mouse wheel event change zoom by delta

Tags: leaflet, zoom, mouse-wheel

I am trying to find a way to change zoom by delta when using mouse wheel event (scroll) in Leaflet.

E.g. current map zoom is on 0 and if "scrolled" into map, zoom should be 5.

Also, zoom change should take zoom location in account.

E.g. map is 1000px * 1000px, then if mouse wheel is done on [x:1000, y:0], then it should be zoomed in that part (in right upper corner) and not random or in center.

**Attempts / Results**

- adding mousewheel listener on map div - zoom delta working by calling zoomIn(), zoom position random, can not get info on coordinates since it is not Leaflet event
- adding mousewheel listener on tile div - not able to do anything with it
- adding zoomstart listener on map - not able to do anything  with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`zoomDelta` map option](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomdelta) to control how many zoom levels the map shall change when using keyboard controls or the zoom buttons, and the [`wheelPxPerZoomLevel` option](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-wheelpxperzoomlevel)  to control how fast the mouse wheel will change zoom levels.

Please note that `scroll` events are finicky, and depend on the web browser and your actual hardware. Some mice scroll in steps, some touchpads report a fine amount of scrolled pixels, some other are just weird. Assume that a "scroll click" is 60 pixels, and adjust the value of `wheelPxPerZoomLevel` accordingly - e.g. if you want to scroll 5 zoom levels at a time, use a value of (60/5)=12, and a `zoomDelta` of 5:

```
var map = L.map('map-container', {
    zoomDelta: 5,
    wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 12 
});
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Don't know how I missed this setting :/. Hopefully it will look good on most browsers and devices. Anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @IvanSanchez's answer, Leaflet from 1.0.0 onwards introduced the concept of fractional zoom levels, so you can zoom in a more controlled way. So you can use, for example,

```js
var map = L.map('map-container', {
    zoomSnap: 0.25,
    zoomDelta: 1,
    wheelPxPerZoomLevel: 60
});
```